# Why does this cron job run?

Tags: cron

I have a `cron` script that runs a few times every day throughout the year. However, around Christmas it should work differently. So my script looks basically like this:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
26 16 * JAN-NOV MON-THU (echo 14 `date`) >> /var/log/cron.www-data 2>&1
26 16 1-18 DEC MON-THU (echo 6 `date`) >> /var/log/cron.www-data 2>&1
```

where I replaced the actual command with a simple `echo` for debugging / demonstration purposes.
For the exceptional case, I added some jobs like

```
26 07 19-24 DEC ? (echo 1 `date` ) >> /var/log/cron.www-data 2>&1
```

that actually work fine.

The problem is, that the second line above (`echo 6`) just got run, today December 19 -- the log file shows

```
6 Tue Dec 19 16:00:01 CET 2017
```

**I guess my question is simply: *Why did this job run*?**

I'm running Linux 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason can be found in `crontab(5)`:

> Commands are executed by cron(8) when the minute, hour, and month of year fields match the current time, and **when at least one of the two day fields (day of month, or day of week) match the current time**.

(*Emphasis added*)

I believe you want your script to run at the specified time from 1-18 December, but only from Monday to Thursday. As you can see from the manual page, `cron` doesn't do this when you specify both day of the month and day of the week. Your command will execute on every day from 1-18 December *and* on any day from Monday to Thursday in December. December 19, 2017 is a Tuesday, hence the script running.

*Note:* the above applies to ISC cron, the default on Debian systems.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes it's easy to overlook such subtleties!

Comment: I just got bit by overlooking this, and found your answer when researching "why".  Who in the heck decided that's the right way to interpret the qualifiers???